# Backup Database, qual ferramenta usar, alternativas, segurança e acesso aos dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, backup, cloud, armazenamento

Não sei se aqui é o lugar correto pra fazer essa pergunta, se não for peço desculpas e excluo a pergunta...

- Onde eu trabalho temos um sistema que trabalha com 2 tipos de database, firebird 2.0 ou MySQL, devido ao banco firebird ficar no lado do cliente, algumas vezes o backup que geramos(e fica na mesma máquina do cliente) se perde por motivos que não temos como prevenir, exemplo: já houve casos que o cliente teve o computador furtado, HD queimando, e essas coisas as quais não temos controle.
- 1º tentativa de solução: Disco removível armazenando o backup.

Isso prevenia os dados serem perdidos por problemas no HD, mas não adiantava nada se o cliente removesse o disco, além de dar erro no caminho quando o backup automático fosse ativado.

- 2º tentativa de solução: MegaSync e similares.

Esta tentativa funcionou corretamente por algum tempo, até percebermos que quando ocorresse alguma falha na internet, queda de energia ou problemas no momento em que o backup estava sendo sincronizado, o arquivo ficava inútil ou se perdia uma quantidade grande de dados.

Após passar por isso me vi obrigado a procurar uma outra solução, cheguei em 3 opções e queria saber se algum de vocês já usou elas ou tem alguma ideia de como controlar a situação.

As opções são:

- [Acronis](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/)
- [Uranium Backup](https://www.uranium-backup.com/pt-br/exchange-bancos-de-dados-sql-server-backup/)
- [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/solutions/architecture/backup-archive-on-premises-applications/)

Sendo as 2 primeiras com ferramentas específicas pra banco de dados...
Se alguém puder ajudar fico grato

Comment: O ideal seria você publicar sua dúvida no https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: A melhor garantia sua seria que o banco não ficasse na mesma máquina do cliente. De qualquer forma, seguindo do jeito que está, seria melhor você implementar uma rotina de sincronismo que leia o firebird de tempos em tempos e realize transações de sincronismo para o seu mysql.

Comment: @AndreMesquita o problema é que não sei quando o cliente em questão está mexendo no banco, e se ocorrer do backup tentar ser sobreescrito enquanto está realizando a sincronização, o mesmo se corrompe e gera uns arquivos "esquisitos" na pasta do MegaSync, por isso estava pensando em uma ferramenta que fizesse o "management" desses dados antes de realizar o upload pra um servidor remoto

Comment: Sugiro que modifique sua pergunta definindo bem qual o problema, deixar 3 opções de programas e essa dúvida como o que seria melhor irá fazer sua pergunta seja fechada como "baseada em opiniões"

Answer (score 2):

Cara primeiro que o arquivo .FDB ou .GDB do firebird não precisa ficar do lado do cliente isso já é errado, se for rede local o server que deve ficar com o arquivo e ele pode ser mapeado pelos clientes, se o server for acesso pela net se faz as configurações no firewall,NAT etc...

Tanto MySql quanto Firebird fazem backup e gera um arquivo, esse arquivo deve obrigatoriamente ser copiado para outro lugar que não seja o próprio HD do server, ai se você vai usar DAT, PENDRIVE, NUVEM, HD externo etc. é por sua conta e risco, cada um tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, e se for essa sua pergunta ( qual é o **melhor** ) provavelmente a pergunta não vai ter resposta **certa** e sim um monte de opiniões.

Comment: Sim, mas existem casos em que o cliente só tem uma máquina, não possibilitando a instalação de um servidor, nos clientes que temos e possuem mais de uma máquina utilizamos um servidor em uma rede local, porém nem sempre conseguimos fazer com que o cliente "abra a mão" para adquirir uma nova máquina

Comment: a solução para seu problema continua sendo a mesma, backup tem que ser copiado para fora da maquina que esta o banco de dados, independente da tecnologia que irá usar para faze-lo, isso backup se não sair da maquina é "cópia" não backup

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro encontrar uma solução que caiba no seu bolso usando o que tem de melhor próximo de você. Os backups podem estar gigantes devido a sua massa de dados de algum tempo de trabalho, mas isso já se trata de buscar a melhor alternativa pra fazer backups menores sem perda de tempo "transmitindo" dados desnecessários.